# at data of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-volley

my response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "statuscode": 200,
    "message": "Record found successfully.",
    "data": {
        "tangible_benefits": "ds1351gsghsdh353535535",
        "intangible_benefits": "shwryw24y43rwehdg135313513",
        "total_annual_savings": "45135432",
        "root_cause_identification": [
            {
                "id": "6",
                "projectid": "1498",
                "step": "6",
                "root_cause_identified": "efficiency",
                "solution_implemented": "efficiency",
                "implementaion_date": "14-01-2020",
                "createdby": "201465",
                "updatedby": "201465",
                "created_date": "2020-01-14 18:04:41",
                "updated_date": "2020-01-14 18:04:41"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

java code

```
try {
            JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);
            if (res.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                JSONArray TQMData = res.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < TQMData.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = TQMData.getJSONObject(i);
                    stepsList.add(new TQMSavedDataModel(obj.getString("tangible_benefits"),
                            obj.getString("intangible_benefits"),
                            obj.getString("total_annual_savings"),
                            (List<RootCauseIdentificationModel>) obj.getJSONObject("root_cause_identification")
                    ));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
```

Comment: Your `data` is actual nested Object, not Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right answer.

```
try {
            JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);

            if (res.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                JSONObject obj = res.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONArray rootCauseIdentificationArray = obj.getJSONArray("root_cause_identification");
                for(int i = 0; i<rootCauseIdentificationArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject objData = rootCauseIdentificationArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    //iterate the object here and add to the list
                    RootCauseIdentificationModel model = new RootCauseIdentificationModel( objData.getString("id"), objData.getString("root_cause_identified"), objData.getString("solution_implemented"), objData.getString("implementaion_date"));
                   dataList.add(model);

                }

                stepsList.add(new TQMSavedDataModel(obj.getString("tangible_benefits"),
                        obj.getString("intangible_benefits"),
                        obj.getString("total_annual_savings"),
                        dataList));
                tangibleBenefits.setText(obj.getString("tangible_benefits"));
                intangibleBenefits.setText( obj.getString("intangible_benefits"));
                annualAmount.setText(obj.getString("total_annual_savings"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try below code:

```
try {
            JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);

            if (res.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

                JSONObject TQMData = res.getJSONObject("data");
                String tangible_benefits = TQMData.getString("tangible_benefits");
                String intangible_benefits = TQMData.getString("intangible_benefits");
                String total_annual_savings = TQMData.getString("total_annual_savings");

                JSONArray root_cause_identification = TQMData.getJSONArray("root_cause_identification");

                for (int i = 0; i < root_cause_identification.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = root_cause_identification.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                    String projectid = jsonObject.getString("projectid");
                    String step = jsonObject.getString("step");
                    String root_cause_identified = jsonObject.getString("root_cause_identified");
                    String solution_implemented = jsonObject.getString("solution_implemented");
                    String implementaion_date = jsonObject.getString("implementaion_date");
                    String createdby = jsonObject.getString("createdby");
                    String updatedby = jsonObject.getString("updatedby");
                    String created_date = jsonObject.getString("created_date");
                    String updated_date = jsonObject.getString("updated_date");
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: i have a model, which is contains, data of tangible_benefits,intangible_benefits,total_annual_savings,root_cause_identification. thats why i using List<RootCauseIdentificationModel>

Answer (score 1):

The response you're getting is a `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below answer, above as per your json sample you are trying to iterate 'data' and 'root_cause_identification' wrongly

```
try {
   JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);

   if (res.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
       JSONObject obj = res.getJSONObject("data");
       JSONArray rootCauseIdentificationArray = obj.getJSONArray("root_cause_identification");
       List<RootCauseIdentificationModel> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
       for(int i = 0; i<routeCauseIdentificationArray.length(); i++){
       JSONObject objData = rootCauseIdentificationArray.getJSONObject(i);
       //iterate the object here and add to the list
       RootCauseIdentificationModel model = new RootCauseIdentificationModel(objData.getString("id"), objData.getString("root_cause_identified"), objData.getString("solution_implemented"), objData.getString("implementaion_date")); 
       tempList.add(model);
   }

   stepsList.add(new TQMSavedDataModel(obj.getString("tangible_benefits"),
                            obj.getString("intangible_benefits"),
                            obj.getString("total_annual_savings"),
                            tempList));
        }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    dialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

Comment: JSONObject obj=res.getJSONArray("data") error in this line

Comment: now my app crash and error is that   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.util.List                                                 this error comes on (List<RootCauseIdentificationModel>) rootCauseIdentificationArray.getJSONObject(0)

Comment: Now this is your task. rootCauseIdentificationArray.getJSONObject(0) is an object you cannot cast it as List<RootCauseIdentificationModel>....so try to create the list with the iterated data from the array of objects

Comment: private ArrayList<RootCauseIdentificationModel> dataList = new ArrayList(); its done , but error are still exist

Comment: public RootCauseIdentificationModel(String id,String rootCauseIdentified, String solutionImplemented,String date){
        this.id=id;
        this.rootCauseIdentified=rootCauseIdentified;
        this.solutionImplemented=solutionImplemented;
        this.date=date;
    }

Comment: onething, i am not want all data from the API side, i need only print root_cause_identified,solution_implemented,implementaion_date in ROOTCauseModel

Comment: and now my app run but throw exception something went wrong

Comment: "Index 1 out of range [0..1)" this the message

Comment: please help me out bro.

Comment: Check the answer change. About the your model data, that you have to do by yourself.

Comment: but one another issue found, tangible_benefits,intangible_benefits,total_annual_savings. these field not print

Comment: Hope u have got the actual answer, printing values and displaying at your screen may be a different problem.

Comment: i want to print this item only by hitting API  {
  "status": "success",
  "statuscode": 200,
  "message": "Record found successfully.",
  "data": {
    "tangible_benefits": "ds1351gsghsdh353535535",
    "intangible_benefits": "shwryw24y43rwehdg135313513",
    "total_annual_savings": "45135432",
    "root_cause_identification": [
      {
        "root_cause_identified": "efficiency",
        "solution_implemented": "efficiency",
        "implementaion_date": "14-01-2020"
      }
    ]
  }
}  and one more problem my dailog.show continuesouly show, i think data not fetch thats why

Comment: please help me bro

Answer (score 0):

First, you should get `data` as JsonObject 
Then, from this object, you can retrieve the array you need :)

```
try {
            JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);

            if (res.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                JSONObject TQMData = res.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONArray arrayTQMData = TQMData.getJSONArray("root_cause_identification");
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayTQMData.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = arrayTQMData.getJSONObject(i);
                    stepsList.add(new TQMSavedDataModel(obj.getString("tangible_benefits"),
                            obj.getString("intangible_benefits"),
                            obj.getString("total_annual_savings"),
                            (List<RootCauseIdentificationModel>) obj.getJSONObject("root_cause_identification")
                    ));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
```

Happy coding !

Comment: I edited my answer, but keep in mind that the data you are retrieving from JSON is NOT part of an array.. `tangible_benefits`, `intangible_benefits `, `total_annual_savings ` are shown only once in the JSON. They are NOT part of an array :)

Comment: obj.getJSONObject("root_cause_identification") this is an array of objects

Comment: please keep in mind, i am using two model in this 1st model is TQMSavedDataModel which contain  tangible_benefits,intangible_benefits ,total_annual_savings and RootCauseIdentificationModel .                                                2nd model is the RootCauseIdentificationModel which contain  id, root_cause_identified,solution_implemented,implementaion_date

Comment: 'root_cause_identification' this keyname at multiple location with multiple types?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);
            if (res.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                JSONObject TQMData = res.getJsonObject("data");
                JSONArray root_cause_identification = TQMData.getJsonArray("root_cause_identification");
                    for(int i=0; i< root_cause_identification.length;i++){
                        JsonObject root_cause_identificationObject = root_cause_identification.get(i);
                        // Unmarshal this for the Bean and add to list

                    }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
```

Comment: obj.getJSONObject("root_cause_identification") this is an array of objects

Comment: obj , not found

Comment: now my app crash and error is that java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.util.List this error comes on (List<RootCauseIdentificationModel>) rootCauseIdentificationArray.getJSONObject(0)

Comment: you need to debug it, the major problem I highlighted

Comment: and it's not a LIst<RootCauseIdentificationModel> you getting, you have to iterate the array and unmarshal for the bean and add to List.

Comment: I made some changes, hope you got the idea