# Index 1 out of range [0..1)

Tags: android, arrays, json

java code

```
try {
    JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);

    if (res.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
        JSONObject obj = res.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray rootCauseIdentificationArray = obj.getJSONArray("root_cause_identification");
        //List<RootCauseIdentificationModel> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<=rootCauseIdentificationArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject objData = rootCauseIdentificationArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //iterate the object here and add to the list
            RootCauseIdentificationModel model = new RootCauseIdentificationModel( objData.getString("root_cause_identified"), objData.getString("solution_implemented"), objData.getString("implementaion_date"));
            dataList.add(model);
        }

        stepsList.add(new TQMSavedDataModel(obj.getString("tangible_benefits"),
            obj.getString("intangible_benefits"),
            obj.getString("total_annual_savings"),
            dataList));
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    dialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

API

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "statuscode": 200,
  "message": "Record found successfully.",
  "data": {
    "tangible_benefits": "ds1351gsghsdh353535535",
    "intangible_benefits": "shwryw24y43rwehdg135313513",
    "total_annual_savings": "45135432",
    "root_cause_identification": [
      {
        "root_cause_identified": "efficiency",
        "solution_implemented": "efficiency",
        "implementaion_date": "14-01-2020"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see in this response, there is one data in response of "root_cause_identification" and application is crashed a FOR loop while doing parsing of response. So what is the cause of crash of app when there is data available?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @DeepakKumar answer has been updated at your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android JSONException index 1 out of range \[0..1\] (Parse 2 json arrays inside 1 loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418094/android-jsonexception-index-1-out-of-range-0-1-parse-2-json-arrays-inside-1)

Comment: You already got answer from your other question [at data of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820204/at-data-of-type-org-json-jsonobject-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray)

Comment: yes i found the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index always start from 0. So your condition in for loop should be,

i **<** rootCauseIdentificationArray.length()

Not this one,

i **<=** rootCauseIdentificationArray.length()

So modify it to,

```
for(int i = 0; i<rootCauseIdentificationArray.length(); i++)
```